# Can I use Sync Framework just for transfering data without provisioning (using sync tables)?

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to configure the framework to transfer records only based on filters without sync tables and all these additionals tables used in a normal synchronization process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't. However, read on for a more complete answer.

The work around:

There is one way to bypass the need for extra tables in your schema. If you use SQL 2008 and sync framework 1.0 objects (SyncAgent, not the SyncOrchestrator), you can use SQL 2008's built-in change tracking. That won't clutter your schema at all. SQL 2008 will still be tracking the changes, you just won't have to see a bunch of tables cluttering up your schema.

The long answer (staying with sync framework 2.* objects):

The sync tables and tracking tables work as part of a set of schema, stored procedures, and processes that make up the sync framework system. Although you might be able to structure a filter that allows you to only select changes, the rest of the system still needs the tracking tables. The tracking tables not only track when a row was inserted/updated, they also track whether the last change was a local change or whether it was applied via the sync framework from a remote database. The tracking of the source of the change is one of the key things that really adds value to the sync framework - and is thus a core concept in the framework.

If you were to try to eliminate the tracking tables, at minimum, you would have to update every stored procedure as well (all 8+ of them for every table...). You can't get rid of the sync tables (schema_info, scope_*) at all - the need for them isn't in stored procedures, it is built into the core of the framework.